# jVectorMap renders too small

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jvectormap

My jVectorMap isn't taking the new height I'm providing on the containing div and only renders at the default (?) height of 54px.

This is in a document.ready function in my scripts.js file:

```js
$('#team-map-usa').vectorMap({
  map: 'us_lcc_en',
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  hoverColor: '#999999',
  color: '#dddddd',
  normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
  values: myData,
  scaleColors: ['#d0c4dc', '#d1b0eb', '#b296cb', '#47006b'],
  onLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
    label.text(code);
  })
});
```

Containing div:

```
    <section id="top">
      <div id="team-map-usa" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    </section>
```

Documentation suggests that if I have a width and height set on the containing div, that should be applied to the created jVectorMap. The div is not hidden at any point (which I read here: [Jvectormap very small on div change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969023/jvectormap-very-small-on-div-change) could be an issue) and `$('#team-map-usa')` clientHeight and clientWidth are both defined when the vectormap is initialized.

This is my first time using jVectorMap and I must be missing something. Any suggestions of how to make the map appear the right size?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem...

Answer (score 9):

If your not including the jquery-jvectormap-2.0.1.css on your page you need to style the content generated by jVectorMap.

In your case adding the following to you styles should do the trick

```
.jvectormap-container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

You can look at the http://jvectormap.com/css/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.1.css to hopefully find all the styles you need.

Comment: For me the solution was to include the `jquery-jvectormap...css` correctly in the page! I misspelled it.

E.g. I was missing this in my the <head> of my HTML: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="bower_components/jvectormap202/dist/css/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.2.css"></script>`

I was using [this Bower variant](https://libraries.io/bower/jvectormap-2.0.2).

Answer (score 2):

You have to include jquery-jvectormap-2.0.4.css on page to solve this issue. Just check if you have misspelled file name or you may have missed to add this on page.

Answer (score 2):

> When you trigger vectorMap() on element that has parent value to
>   **display: none** it will render as extra small. So solutions is to use
>   **visibility: hidden** rather that display: none

You can run this code and check if map resize to normal state:

> window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, but may be helpful:

`html, body, #mapa, #mapa_dos{
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }`

In the example that I'm handling, I have two maps with the id="mapa" and id="mapa_dos". 
The containers of the div are the html and body tags, so displays the maps in the entire screen.